# How to set up Python in a web server?

Tags: python, windows, django

Not exactly about programming, but I need help with this.

I'm running a development sever with WampServer. I want to install Python (because I prefer to use Python over PHP), but it seems there isn't an obvious choice. I've read about mod_python and WSGI, and about how the latter is better.

However, from what I gathered (I may be wrong) you have to do more low-level stuff with WSGI than with PHP. So I researched about Django, but it seems too complex for what I want.

So, what recommendations would you give to a newbie in this area?

Again, sorry if this isn't about programming, but it's related, and this seems like a nice place to ask.

Comment: Heh, should this be on http://serverfault.com/, the sister site of SO? It is in private beta, and you need 100 SO rep to get there, but you can also request access from the admins, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/

Comment: This is the standard edge case between SO and SF.  IMO, it's programming since it is about the development of applications in WSGI, CGI or Django.  Not the configuration of the server or OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is a great little python tool (werkzeug) that works with mod_wsgi for creating simple apps that dont need database backends with CMS's, such as calculators ..  They've even got a nifty [screencast](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/wiki30/) where they create a simple wiki in 30 minutes.

You can always add something like SQLAlchemy/FormAlchemy later on if you eventually do want to have a ORM and CMS.

Avoid mod_python tho, it's got a pretty big memory footprint and it's actually a bit harder to install and set up than mod_wsgi, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Django is not a web server, but a web application framework.

If you want a bare-bones Python webserver capable of some dynamic and some static content, have a look at [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) to embed Python in Apache.  It works very, very well.

"However, from what I gathered (I may be wrong) you have to do more low-level stuff with WSGI than with PHP. So I researched about Django, but it seems too complex for what I want."

1. If you try to write your entire application as a WSGI-compliant application, directly accessed via mod_wsgi, you will reinvent the wheel.
2. If you try to write your application in Django, you will have stuff up and running in the space of a few hours.  Django is not "too complex" -- it's complete.  You don't have to use all of it, but -- for any realistic application -- you'll need most of it.  In particular, the built-in admin will save you mountains of programming.

Comment: But can Django be used just as a collection of tools to make development easier? The tutorials at the website make it look almost like a CMS.

Comment: @ReyJavik:  Django is just a framework -- emphatically not a CMS.  There are several CMS available, written in Django.  http://django-cms.org/, also http://www.ellingtoncms.com/.

Answer (score 0):

To use python with your Apache server you need to install mod_python the following links should help you out a bit.

- http://httpd.apache.org/modules/python-download.cgi
- http://www.modpython.org/

Comment: If I could -1 an elitist, "you have to do everything yourself even if it's already been done" comment, I would do it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly a development server you're setting up, and not a machine that will be promoted to production at some point, Django has a [built-in development webserver](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) that requires no Apache configuration.

Your observation about the low-level work reflects some of the differences between PHP and Python. PHP is a language designed from the start for the primary purpose of making web pages. Python is a language. Mod_Python and Mod_WSGI give the input to/output from that language a way to live in a web request/response environment. Django adds web-aware framework conveniences.

You mention that python seems too complex for what you want, which rather begs the question: what do you want? :-)

Comment: Well, I want a kind of simple website. I'll have a special calculator (which I have already done in PHP), and maybe I'll make a simple blog as a learning experience. It's not that I can't use PHP, it's that I don't want to.